# Calculate position of N points around given point in 3d space?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Sorry if I used wrong words - English is not my native language, and I never actually studied geometry.

For a project I'm working on, I need to calculate set of points, that:

- are in given, constant, distance from given source point
- are equally spaced from each other
- surround the source point from all sides

In 2d, I could have done it, but in 3d I'm at loss.

For 4 points, the points would looks like "pyramid" with source point inside, in the middle. For 6 points, I could have got 4 points in one plane, 90 degrees from each other, and 2 points on "poles". But how to calculate it for (more or less) any number of points?

Comment: Looking at [regular polyhedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They won't be truly equidistant from the neighbors unless they are on a Platonic solid.  That only works for $4,6,8,12,$ or $20$ points.  The best alternate packings are often quite complicated.  [This site](http://bendwavy.org/sphere.htm) has a large bibliography.  It has been considered [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere)  You can search for "packing points on a sphere" and find many hits.